# Meaning of "She said we should both see other men"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

The following sentence conflicts in my head: "**She [girlfriend] said we should both see other men**".
The people in question are in a monogamous heterosexual relationship. Is this sentence correct?

---

I'll try to explain why I think it's conflicting.

"You should see (an)**other** man/men"
Meaning: The person in question is seeing (a) man/men, and should see (an)other man/men.

"We should both see **other** men"
Meaning: The people in question are both seeing men, and should see other men.

The "**other**" indicates that they are already seeing men.
So with that logic, the sentence "She [girlfriend] said we should both see other men" means that they are both seeing men already, and should see other men.
But they are not seeing other men already if they are in monogamous heterosexual relationship. So the sentence is conflicting in meaning and should be "She said I should see a man, and she needs to see another man".

Is my logic flawed?
(I'm a native Dutch speaker, maybe I'm incorrectly transporting Dutch language logic into this)

Comment: I think your analysis is correct. Maybe the sentence is for humorous effect?

Comment: Yes, it's a meme. It probably wouldn't be funny to people if the "correct" version of the sentence would be used. But the confusing conflict also prevents me from finding it humorous.

Comment: It means that she thinks that you're gay.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not looking for an explanation of the intended message. Just the actual sentence they use and whether it is correct.

Comment: "Other" can simply mean a man other than yourself.

Comment: That’s not at all clear but if you mean the grammar alone, there might be a question whether it should be *both* or *each* see other men.

 *We should both see other men* could (just) mean *people*.

It could also mean you don’t have enough male friends straight, gay, bi- or whatever.